# does expired certificate affects test flights app

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, testflight

I have upload an app to testflight and also submitted for approval and got approved

Just noticed that the certificate expires soon

- will the testers still able to test the app once the certificate expires?
- Can we still push to appstore as its already been approved?
- Just googled and found mixed info so kind of not sure.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can not test your application if the certificate expires. I am not sure if it can push to the Appstore. But if you want to upgrade the application then you must reapply for a new certificate. So I think the certificate is necessary, even though it has been approved.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and your time - the problem is I need to advice the client with some confidence as it has people's time implication to retest the app. My understing was that once in test flight apple re-signs the app and its not affected but not sure . everything is abit vague